# How to write with any color?

Tags: discussion, support

I’m asking this because, I have a trouble on finding “how to write with blue or any other colors” and I try to find out by viewing on edit, but it does not work at all to me even if I copy the same.

**Q-1:** [How can I write with blue or with any color like other users do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osEED.png)

**Q-2:** [It is possible to do that on any telephone?][2]

**Q-3:** Oh and, can you tell me how to make any color be bold as in the picture with “READ EVERYTHING WE ARE ABOUT TO TELL YOU”?

**Q-4:** When do we use blue, green or red or any color in bold?

**Q-5:** When do we use any color?

I’m asking this because, I want to improve in a very clear question and answer, and because I’m tired of using always black bold. I want to use other colors too.

**Q-6:** Can you make for me a list of what are the colors made on **Stack Exchange** ?

When I try to put like this [wsidbe][2] it suppose to turn into blue color, but to me it does not. I don’t know where I do wrong. As you see this picture:

[image]

It shows blue bold on [**READ EVERYTHING WE ARE ABOUT TO TELL YOU**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osEED.png)

On the other post **How can I write in any color** I forgot to describe, to tell you this so I write again because, I see no one will check it. Can anyone please answer me this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not really.

Colors are controlled by the CSS of the page; in the case of your screenshot, the "blue" text is only blue because they're links to other pages. Depending on the CSS being used by the site, this could literally be rendered as any other color (for example, [links to other pages](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/how-to-write-with-any-color) are orange on this meta) and you have no control over that.

If you want to know how to format your posts, check our [Markdown Help](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page: Those are the formatting options available to everybody, and "color" is not one of them.